# Run circuit N times in Q#

Tags: programming, q#

I use dotnet run command to run my .qs quantum circuit. Is there a way to run my circuit N times, and get results of each run (like the shots parameter in Qiskit) ?

Thank you.

Comment: You could create a python or C# host program to further process data. However, there must be a dotnet command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quantum programs in Q# can include classical logic as well as low-level quantum instructions, such that you can directly include the "shot" concept from circuits in your Q# programs by using a `for`-loop.

```
@EntryPoint()
operation RunSeveralTimes(nTimes : Int) : Result[] {
    mutable results = new Result[nTimes];
    for (idx in 0..nTimes - 1) {
        set results w/= idx <- DoSomething();
    }
    return results;
}
```

When running this program with `dotnet run`, you can now pass `--n-times` as a command-line argument to control how many times your `DoSomething()` operation gets called. Similarly, if you're using Q# in Jupyter Notebooks, you can use a command like `%simulate RunSeveralTimes nTimes=50`. From Python interoperability, you can pass `nTimes` as a keyword argument, e.g.: `RunSeveralTimes.simulate(nTimes=50)`.

The Q# standard libraries also offer several functions and operations to make this sort of loop easier to write:

- [`EstimateFrequency`](https://docs.microsoft.com/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.characterization.estimatefrequency) and [`EstimateFrequencyA`](https://docs.microsoft.com/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.characterization.estimatefrequencya): run an operation many times, and collect the probability with which a measurement at the end returns `One`.
- [`DrawMany`](https://docs.microsoft.com/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.arrays.drawmany): run an operation many times with the same input, and collect all outputs.
- [`ForEach`](https://docs.microsoft.com/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.arrays.foreach): run an operation once for each of many inputs, and collect all outputs.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Jonathcraft, it's possible to modify the host program. For example, set the driver of the Q# program to be C#, then call the Q# program multiple times with a for loop.